# How to use @value tag in javadoc?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

I am using a class with private constructor instead of an enum (this is a requirement). And now I am trying to add javadoc tags to document each `public static final` entity.

1) What is prefered place to put javadoc tags: like `ob1` or `ob2`?

2) Both options generate error in IDEA 
`@value tag must reference field with a constant intializer.`

```
/**
 * {@value #ob1} object1 description
 */

public class MyClass {
    public static final Object ob1 = new Object();

    /**
     * {@value #ob2} object2 description
     */ 
    public static final Object ob2 = new Object();

    private MyClass() {}   
}
```

Comment: Try using non-IDEA specific javadoc. Unless this is somehow in the javadoc spec and I haven't heard of it... You can leave the whole @value part out.

Comment: @Kayaman, I don't think it is IDEA-specific tag.

Comment: @value is not IDEA specific. Introduced in 1.4, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#value

Comment: Yes, I know @value isn't IDEA specific, however I've seen it in method javadocs only. If you just enter the description next to the field it should generate correctly (and hopefully without error).

Answer (score 39):

I don't think Kayaman's answer is sufficient as the question is how to use the @value tag in javadocs.

I think the problem lies in the fact that the value of the field being referenced is not a literal value.

In eclipse, when you have

```
/**
 * {@value #ob2} object2 description
 */ 
public static final Object ob2 = new Object();
```

the generated Javadocs are *{@value #ob2} object2 description*. However, when you have

```
/**
 * {@value #ob2} object2 description
 */ 
public static final String ob2 = "hello";
```

the generated Javadocs are *"hello" object2 description* (the expected output).

So, in summary, you are using the @value tag correctly in the javadocs but the value will only be rendered correctly if the field has been initialised with a literal value.

Comment: To add to @JamesB answer, the value the `@value` parameter references has to be a constant (i.e. static and final) and be of a type that has a constant initializer. In _general_, this means Strings and primitives.

Comment: I fixed a similar error in my project by changing the `@value` to an `@link`.

Comment: Worth noting that you can _only_ use `@value` within the same class (i.e. FQN prefixes before the `#` won't work)

Comment: @earcam The Netbeans Javadoc tab resolves the \@value tag even with prefixes before the #. Possibly other IDEs do as well. Maybe the actual Javadoc tool (html generation) doesn't resolve them though -- I didn't test this.

Answer (score 5):

> 2) Both options generate error in IDEA @value tag must reference field with a constant intializer.

**It does not make much sense to add [non-constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) to the Javadoc.**

At first, one might think that the most sensible behavior would be to add a `toString` to the Javadoc. But then, what happens if you had a mutable object like:

```
class MutableInteger {
    public int i;
    public String toString() { return Integer.toString(i); }
}
```

and a Javadoc like:

```
/**
 * {@value #obj}
 */
class Class {
    public static final MutableInteger obj = new MutableInteger(0);
}
```

Then one could simply do later on:

```
Class.obj.i = 1;
```

so adding `0` to the Javadoc wouldn't mean much.

It only works for strings because they are immutable and the JLS explicitly says so: there is no way for you to tell the compiler that on a custom class.

Comment: Does this only work for constant values?